# Can Jmeter repoduce HTTP request by result tree log?

Tags: jmeter

I used Random Order Controller to monitor monkey test,
and save all the information in result tree log(save as .xml).

Now I want to reproduce the request API with same sequence in the log.

Is there any way do that?
Like import the log and reproduce the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what you're doing when using any form of random in your tests because it breaks [tests repeatability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) feature.

I'm not aware of any existing solutions allowing replaying requests stored in the [.jtl results files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), if I had to do this I would consider the following options:

1. Writing my own implementation of the [Access Log Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.html)
2. Or use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to read the .jtl file and populate HTTP Request sampler's URL, body data, headers and so on using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) and `sampler` shorthand for the [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class instance

Comment: I have been trying option 2, but still fail. I don't understand how to combine Groovy language and HTTPSamplerProxy, could you provide a easy example? Thanks a lot.